# Optimization mysql very slowly

Tags: mysql, php, ubuntu

Hello I have a server in kimsufi 2gb RAM and 500gb storage but the query with php mysql is very slowly

I have change innodb buffer pool size to 500M but i have error `too many connections,` i add `max connection` to 500

Why my server is slowly and have many connection (with buffer 500M, if i have buffer 2M i dont have error too many connection) ?

Thanks for your help

My.cnf :

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 
 
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0
 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
 
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking<br>
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover          = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 500
max_user_connections    = 0
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 16M
query_cache_size        = 1M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
 
#innodb_buffer_pool_size=500M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
#innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
#innodb_thread_concurrency=2
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
 
[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition
 
[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
 
#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Yes sorry i have added commented but with 500 i have too many connection bug i need to add max connection=500 for not bug

Comment: I have seek this in the web https://gist.github.com/scottvrosenthal/5383554 its good configuration ? Thanks you